# Recover deleted full disk encryption partition

Tags: partitioning, encryption, data-recovery, gparted, luks

**What I have:**

I have Xubuntu 14.04 installed on 500 GB HDD. The HDD consists of:

1. Some small partition that seems to be for some EFI stuff
2. a partition that holds /boot
3. some free space at the end of the HDD
4. and in between a partition (lvm?) that was created using the full disk encryption option of the Xubuntu install wizard

No. 4 holds the actual system (except /boot of course) and a swap partition.

**What I did:**
Being tired and under time pressure, I deleted No. 4 (using gparted). I intended to delete some partition on an USB key but wasn't paying attention (stupid, I know). As everythign was still working I thought I had deleted said USB Key partition and still saved files to the then already deleted partition. All went fine, so I didn't think anything was broken.

I switched off the computer, when I turned it on again it wouldn't boot. It takes a long time (obviously searching for the gone lvm-partition) and then sends me to a initramfs prompt.

I found out testdisk was some utility to recover deleted partitions. I tried out some rescue system (ALT Linux) with testdisk 6.14 and then, when I realized there's a version 7 of it, I even tried testdisk 7.00 (static). This gives me (I treid quick search and deep search) more then the one partition I was looking for, so I hesitated doing anything I don't fully understand.

After an internet search, I found out that I could use hexeditor to look for the luks header (by searching for '4c554b53babe'). I did find two luks headers on the drive. One at

One at 0x206FEBD4/0x7470C06000

and

one at 0x2F500000/0x7470C06000

**What I presume:**
I presume that the actual data is intact, as I only deleted the partition in gaparted which I think only means some altering in the partition table, so resetting the partition table to normal would set the whole system back to normal.
I do have /boot so I should be able to decrypt the lvm partition and then get to the presumably intact ext4 partition.
I am not sure if I need to know the exact size of the lvm partition (as noted, there was some free space at the end of the drive, I don't know why, it wasn't much and this was how the Xubuntu install left it) or if that might be stored somewhere in the luks header or somewhere else.

**What I hope:**
I hope that by some command line magic I am yet not capable of, I can reset the disk to normal so I can boot into my system as I always did.

Sorry for the lengthy explaination, I want to provide you with a smuch info as possible. If you need more, do tell me and I'll deliver.

Answer (score 1):

Just came back after over two years and saw some people looked at the question so there might be in interest in how I solved the problem:

It was really just the partition table. By just recreating the before deleted lvm partition, all went back to normal.

I didn't even have to remember the exact size of the lvm partition, I just opened gparted and created a new partition to the end of the disk, using all free space. The data was still there, the system is still running today (though updated to recent Xubuntu).